# How I compile multiprecision.org MPC code?

Tags: c++, g++, mpc

I am trying to use the MPC library from [www.multiprecision.org](http://www.multiprecision.org/).
I want to compile the C++ code with g++ under Linux, with GMP and MPFR both installed. The point is I don't know what compiler flags I should use.

Answer (score 2):

you need to link with libmpc:

```
gcc foo.c -o foo -lmpc
```

I test it with mpc from ubuntu packages:

```
sudo aptitude install libmpc-dev libmpc2
```

my foo.c looks like:

```
#include "mpc.h"

int main() {
    mpc_t x;
    mpc_init2 (x, 256);
    return 0;
}
```